# Why does dragging a space in Spaces lag awfully?

Tags: snow-leopard, spaces

All of a sudden, dragging a space in spaces to switch it for another space lags and takes for ever.

Why? any solutions? It didn't happen before.

There are not many apps open, memory's fine, dragging windows in Spaces works great, switching into and out of spaces works fast too.

See: [video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zobxx8x9qXM).

PS: Embedding videos here would be nice wouldn't it?

Spec: 13' MacBook, 10.6.6 OS, 2GB Ram, 2.226 Ghz Core 2 Duo

Comment: Is that video Realtime? Did you restart your computer?

Comment: Have almost the same here - '13 MBP 7,1 with 10.6.7 and 8GB ram. What are your specs/versions?

Comment: @Martín yes, it's real time, and has been happening for many days, so yes, restarted many times. (joé chaval!)

Comment: @mspasov 13' MacBook, 10.6.6 OS, 2GB Ram, 2.226 Ghz Core 2 Duo.  
PS: 10.6.7 is out already? gonna update

Comment: @Petruza This is certainly something I have never seen before, does this happen under any user? Have you tried creating a different user and using spaces from there to see if it exhibits the same lag?

Comment: @Martín nope, gonna try

Comment: @Petruza Let us know. This will basically help us determine if this is a problem that is caused by a specific process or file that belongs to a user or a system wide problem.

Comment: Please post the output of System.log and kernel.log while reproducing the behavior. It sounds you have a broken kext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the OS and the problem went away.
I'll mark this answer as correct until someone comes with a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Mine is slow too. Note that it works with the mouse, not the graphic, so you can click, drag, release, and move out of Spaces, and the effect will have worked, even if the graphics didn't finish yet.

Also, dragging an empty space is, for me, much faster, so if I want to swap an active work space with an empty one, it is better to drag the empty to the active than the active to the empty.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can't move out of spaces ( neither with a key shortcut or a screen corner ) until the slow animation finishes.  And in my case even dragging one empty space on top of another empty space is as slow as any other case, so, no workaround :(